# htaccess rewrite folders to query string in MODx

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string, modx

I'm trying to mod_rewrite a URL folder structure to a query string internally but retain the original URL... 
ie. http://www.mysite.com/employers/events/2013/02
becomes: 
http://www.mysite.com/employers/events/?e_year=2013&e_month=02
...internally. From the browser I'd like to see the original folder-based URL. My efforts have the URL being rewritten properly but the browser shows the query string URL instead. My code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^employers/events/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /employers/events/?e_year=$1&e_month=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^employers/events/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /employers/events/?e_year=$1&e_month=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The second rule is just to catch the version with a trailing slash.

Many thanks in advance, this is causing me great pain.

## Update:

This is what's being passed:

```
Array ( [q] => employers/events/ [e_year] => 2013 [e_month] => 02 )
```

So MODx is clearly sabotaging things internally.. not the best news but a bit of closure at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `RewriteBase /` does nothing if the `.htaccess` file is in the document root. Remove it
2. I don't think you need the forward-slash prefix on your substitution. Also, try this single rule

   ```
   RewriteRule ^employers/events/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/? employers/events/?e_year=$1&e_month=$2 [L,QSA]
   ```

I've tested this locally and it works fine using the following `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^a/b/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/? /a/b/?y=$1&m=$2 [L,QSA]
```

### Update

Using a stand-alone example, your rewrite rules should result in the following query params being passed to the MODx `index.php` file

```
Array
(
    [q] => employers/events/
    [e_year] => 2013
    [e_month] => 02
)
```

What MODx does with this, I can't say

Comment: Thanks Phil... same still happens at the mo - the query version is still visible from the browser. There's no redirect that should be making it visible from the frontend. Not sure if modX is messing around with the links internally either.. I can't find anything that'd suggest it is.

Comment: @SteveH Is this all that's in `.htaccess`? MODx has its own set of rules but only if you enable *friendly URLs* and rename the `ht.access` file

Comment: I'm using the friendly URLs standard rules placed after mine... (updated question with code)

I fear something else in modX is screwing with my routes... really what I didn't want to happen. It's a microsite based on the main site built by another party. Needle in haystack :(

Comment: @SteveH Is there an actual file (`index.php` or similar) in `employers/events/`? If so, you should put that in your `RewriteRule` (see my updated answer). If there is nothing there, MODx will rewrite the URL and I'm not exactly sure what would happen then

Comment: Yeah it's a virtual directory routed within modX.. your updated code gave a 404 on employers/events/index.php but the query parameter's were still passed.

Comment: @SteveH I've removed the `index.php` references from the rewrite rules. I've also added some extra information. In my tests, the URL remains `employers/events/2013/02`

Comment: Thanks Phil, much appreciated... I can eliminate this path of investigation at least :)